# How to build ionic app for windows phone?

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

**Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-windows@~5.0.0**
**Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.**

Comment: do not mention version of platform while adding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ionic commands have changed. To add windows platform to ionic app run `cordova platforms add windows`

Answer (score 2):

`ionic platform add windows
ionic build windows --prod`

and add preference to your app
`<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />`

Comment: i try to run `ionic platform add windows` command in power shell .then i got this error.

Comment: did you specified any version while adding platform?

Comment: Ionic version 2

Comment: i am also added this code `<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />` in config file.but again its produce the same error to me.

Comment: I think the reason is you are adding windows platform version cordova-windows@~5.0.0. try to add higher versions .ref this link for windows platform versions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx